# How to create a series of numbers using Pandas in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, range, series

I am new to python and have recently learnt to create a series in python using Pandas. I can define a series eg:  `x = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])` but how to define the series for a range, say 1 to 100 rather than typing all elements from 1 to 100?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

As seen in [the docs for pandas.Series](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.html), all that is required for your `data` parameter is an *array-like, dict, or scalar value*. Hence to create a series for a range, you can do exactly the same as you would to create a list for a range.

```
one_to_hundred = pd.Series(range(1,101))
```

Answer (score 17):

```
one_to_hundred=pd.Series(np.arange(1,101,1))
```

This is the correct answer where you create a series using the numpy arange function which creates a range starting with 1 till 100 by incrementing 1.

Answer (score 5):

There's also this:

```
one_to_hundred = pd.RangeIndex(1, 101).to_series()
```

I'm still looking for a pandas function that creates a series containing a range (sequence) of numbers directly, but I don't think it exists.

Answer (score 2):

try `pd.Series([0 for i in range(20)])`.
It will create a pd series with 20 rows

Comment: list comprehension is unnecessary in this case -- can just do `pd.Series(range(20))`

Comment: This creates a series with 20 zeroes. You need `[i for i in range(20)]`. Or just `list(range(20))` or `range(20)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
num=np.arange(1,101)

s = pd.Series(num)
```

see the solution just change whatever you want. and for details about `np.arange` see
below link
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html